# column to row conversion of data in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have data into below format in source table  :

```
     MTH_ID    VOL

   201306   29699420633
   201307   31573662296
   201308   31482365216
   201309   31037480379
   201310   33828084122
```

I want to write a sql query in netezza to convert data into below format

```
201306          201307      201308       201309       201310

29699420633   31573662296   31482365216   31037480379    33828084122
```

In source table I have more than 50 rows and above data is just sample data.
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing about Netezza, but I don't think this could (or should) be done using SQL in any convenient way.

Comment: Use Nzlua function https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/forums/html/topic?id=33f35cc8-1d09-4444-93ab-493454a020ab

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes excel can be your best **IDE**. 
First grab the distinct list of mth_ids.

```
select distinct mth_id 
from table 
order by 1
```

Copy the list and paste in excel.  Add a formula to build the case statement.
[image]

Paste case statement from Excel to IDE and complete the query:

```
select sum(case when mth_id = 201306 then vol else null end) as "201306"
,sum(case when mth_id = 201307 then vol else null end) as "201307"
,sum(case when mth_id = 201308 then vol else null end) as "201308"
,sum(case when mth_id = 201309 then vol else null end) as "201309"
,sum(case when mth_id = 201310 then vol else null end) as "201310"
from table
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But mth_id column always has different number of rows with different values.

Comment: If you need to automate it rather then one time run it.  You would use a scripting language.